# UIAlertController changes color of button with corner radius

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

Code for alert controller is pretty standard.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
    // ...
}
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in
    // ...
}
alertController.addAction(OKAction)

let destroyAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Destroy", style: .Destructive) { (action) in
    //...
}
alertController.addAction(destroyAction)

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
    // ...
}
```

So, after I taped any button in alert controller it dismisses, but now all my buttons with corner radius in view changed background color to blue. 
If I don't set button corner radius - everything works fine.
Is there a workaround to that problem?

Comment: I don't think your issue is in any relations to the `UIAlertController`, you might have done something silly somewhere else which makes those ad-hoc background-colour changes on the rest of the layout.

Comment: I do this in several views, and anytime it repeats. And buttons without corner radius works without issues. To set corner radius I use: `button.layer.cornerRadius = 10`